# serenity configuration via pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, serenity-bdd

I have a java project contains some serenity tests. When I execute `mvn test verify -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\dev\applications\chrome\chromedriver-2.29.exe -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome` then my build works fine.

I would like to add the two -D properties to maven pom.xml as a profile as it is written in the serenity documentation but the following code snippet does not work:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>firefox</id>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>chrome</id>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
            <webdriver.chrome.driver>c:\\dev\\applications\\chrome\\chromedriver-2.29.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Maven command what I used: `mvn clean test verify -Pchrome`

I also tried to add the variables to my pom.xml as system variables but it did not work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
            <webdriver.chrome.driver>c:/dev/applications/chrome/chromedriver-2.29.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What is wrong with my pom file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what was wrong but it is working now after restarting my IDE. My IDE was running for a while (more then a week).

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple "hello-world" application to demonstrate how Serenity and JBehave work together. [Link to the java project](https://github.com/zappee/serenity-ebay-demo).